# str_replace() doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, string, encoding, str-replace, html-entities

I have a string like this :

```
$string = "somehting<br><br>";
```

When I try `str_replace()` like this:

```
echo str_replace("<br>","<c>",$string);
```

The output string doesn't change at all.

What I tried:

```
echo mb_detect_encoding($string); // returns UTF-8
var_dump(strpos($string, "<br>")); // bool(false)
```

I have edited the string with [html dom node class](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/) before and now I really don't know what is wrong.

I have tried to reproduce the problem on sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com with real string and it works.

So I am unable to reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you want to remove html tags then why not use `strip_tags()`

Comment: I want to replace them not remove them

Comment: It is working as expected. https://eval.in/408878

Comment: [**Can't reproduce the problem**](http://3v4l.org/T8VB8) Please show us your **full** and **real** code

Comment: if `var_dump(strpos($string, "<br>"));` gives false, then there isn't a `<br>` in $string

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the problem too on sandbox even with real code but still am not unable to solve this problem.

Comment: @JTC What is the **exact** output of: `var_dump($string);` if you take it from the source code? Maybe your `>` and `<` are encoded.

Comment: I can see there is a `<br>` tag in the string yet  `strpos` return false, so i think its encoding problem but i can't figure out what problem exactly.

Comment: @JTC What is the output of: `highlight_string($string);` ?

Comment: I have updated the answer with `var_dump($real_string;)`

Comment: @JTC please see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as it turns out. Your string is encoded with html-entities. So you see this by simply looking into the source code or using [`highlight_string($yourString)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php) and then you will see: `&lt;` instead of `<`.

To decode it back simply use [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php). As example:

```
$string = str_replace("<br>","<c>", html_entity_decode($string));
highlight_string($string);
```

Answer (score 0):

It does replace `<br>` for `<c>`. It just shows up as blank. If you add `htmlspecialchars()` you can see it did replace.

```
<?php
$string = "somehting<br><br>";
$string = htmlspecialchars(str_replace("<br>","<c>",$string));

var_dump(strpos($string, htmlspecialchars("<c>"))); // int(9)
```